Animated animals soccer match with human referee
In early 80s, I watched a clip (10-15 minutes) about a soccer/football game. It was about a match between animals (all animated) and a human (real, not animated) was the referee.
All details are based on my memory, which may not be 100% accurate.
One team had yellow uniform, captained by a lion. The other had blue uniform. Goal keeper for yellow team was an elephant, and for blue team it was a chimpanzee/money who was constantly hanging from the top pole bar.
There was a lot of chaos during the match. The referee got injured several times. Two vultures were nurses carrying a stretcher. At the end, the soccer ball is deflated completely and the lion blew it to score a goal.
I found it later that this clip was from a movie. What is the name of this movie?

Sounds like Bedknobs & Broomsticks from 1971. The human referee, the blue & yellow jerseys, the various animals you've described... it's all there. You can see the match here.

There was a similar answer once, but that question was way too broad: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16178/movie-with-animals-and-a-football-game Your question is much better & more detailed.
